# Output formatting print with two decimal places and commas for place holders

Tags: java

How do you formatt output?

my code is:

```
package gradplanner;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class GradPlanner {

int cuToComp;
int cuPerTerm;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    final double COST = 2890.00; //flat-rate tuition rate charged per term
    final int MONPERTERM = 6; //number of months per term
    int cuToCompTotal = 0;   
    int numTerm;
    int numMonToComp;
    double tuition;



      //prompt for user to input the number of CUs for each individual course remaining.
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Please enter the number of CUs for each individual course you have remaining, Entering a - number when finished. ");     
    int cuToComp = in.nextInt();



      //add all CUs from individual courses to find the Total number of CUs left to complete.
    while (cuToComp > 0)
    {
      cuToCompTotal += cuToComp;

      System.out.print("Please enter the number of CUs for each individual course you have remaining, Entering a - number when finished. ");
      cuToComp = in.nextInt();
    }

    System.out.println("The total number of CUs left is " + cuToCompTotal);



      //prompt for user to input how many CUs they plan to take per term.
    System.out.print("How many credit units do you intend to take per term? ");
    int cuPerTerm = in.nextInt();

        if (cuPerTerm < 12) //validate input - Undergraduate Students Must enroll in a minimum of 12 CUs per term
        {
            System.out.print("Undergraduate Students must enroll in a Minimum of 12 CUs per Term. ");
                while(cuPerTerm < 12){
                    System.out.print("How many credit units do you intend to take per term? ");
                    cuPerTerm = in.nextInt();
                }
        }


        //Calculate the number of terms remaining, if a remain is present increase number of terms by 1.   
     numTerm = cuToCompTotal/cuPerTerm;
        if (cuToCompTotal%cuPerTerm > 0)
        {
          numTerm = numTerm + 1;  
        }
     System.out.println("The Number of Terms you have left is " + numTerm + " Terms. ");



       //Calculate the number of Months left to complete
     numMonToComp = numTerm * MONPERTERM;
     System.out.println("Which is " + numMonToComp + " Months. ");



       //calculate the tuition cost based on the number of terms left to complete.
     tuition = numTerm * COST;
     System.out.println("Your Total Tuition Cost is: " + "$" + tuition +" . ");

}
```

}

the final line System.out.println("Your Total Tuition Cost is: " + "$" + tuition +" . ");
I need to format it so that it has two decimal places (amount.00) as well as commas for place holders.

I've tried

```
System.out.printf("Your Total Tuition Cost is: " + "$%.2f" + tuition +" . ");
```

however I get an error!!!!

so I added

```
NumberFormat my = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.US);
     my.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
     my.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
     String str = my.format(tuition);
     System.out.printf("Your Total Tuition Cost is: $",    (NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.US).format(tuition)));
```

which outputs

```
Your Total Tuition Cost is: $BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 13 seconds)
```

What is my mistake???

also there will never be a decimal value the xx.00 will always be .00 (does that matter?)

Comment: With place holders, do you mean `123,456.12` or `123456,12`?

Comment: yes i am trying to format it like 123,456.12

Comment: use the `NumberFormat` example from my answer below. Just replace 123456.12 with your `tuition` variable.

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg I updated my question, any advice? thanks for all the help already.

Comment: Use `System.out.printf("Your Total Tuition Cost is: $" + str);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best alternative is to use the [NumberFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html) class, which is better when you want to customize things like decimal separators and placeholders.

Since the output you seem to be looking for is the US standard, you can simply use this:

```
NumberFormat my = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.US);
my.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
my.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
String str = my.format(123456.1234);
```

Another alternative that could be used if it weren't for your placeholder-requirement is to use `String.format`-method.

An easy way in many cases is to use the `String.format` method, this line will output like `123456.12`

```
String.format("Your total cost is : $%.02f", tuition);
```

Comment: What about the commas?

Comment: I would argue that a pre-compiled `MessageFormat` is a little more efficient allows and you to place the messages into an external properties file; while improves maintainability.

Comment: You should just delete the information on `String.format` because that doesn't meet the OP's requirements. You might also mention that NumberFormat is locale-specific.

Comment: I get an error? do I need to add the string.format inside the system.out.print? or just the code you mentioned and delete the system.out?

Comment: @DaoWen Minimized the information about String.format and created a one-liner for the NumberFormat usage.

Comment: @JessicaRush The codes I have provided (I really recommend using the `NumberFormat`-one) gives you a string, so yes, you will need to use `System.out.print` or similar to output the string.

Comment: @JessicaRush For the String.format version, use `System.out.printf(String.format("Your Total Tuition Cost is: " + "$%.2f . ", tuition));` although I recommend `System.out.printf(NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.US).format(tuition));`

Comment: You really need to set the number of decimal places too... What happens when you call this with `1.0` or `3.14159265359`?

Comment: @DaoWen Damn it, there goes my one-liner :) Read the updated answer. Anything I missed now?

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, none of the answers here have mentioned currency formatting:

```
System.out.println("Your Total Tuition Cost is: " + 
    NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().format(tuition));
```

You can also do the same thing with [`MessageFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html), which you might or might not find easier to use:

```
System.out.println(
    MessageFormat.format("Your Total Tuition Cost is: {0,number,currency}",
        tuition));
```